# Label 3Dplot points + update

Tags: matplotlib, label, annotate

I'm quite new with python and matplotlib and this website helped me a lot. but I couldn't find a complete answer about this subject.

I would like to annotate the point of a 3d plot using matplotlib, so after some research I found this peace of code :
[Matplotlib: Annotating a 3D scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)

```
    import pylab
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
    fig = pylab.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
    x = y = z = [1, 2, 3]
    sc = ax.scatter(x,y,z)
    # now try to get the display coordinates of the first point

    x2, y2, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(1,1,1, ax.get_proj())

    label = pylab.annotate(
        "this", 
        xy = (x2, y2), xytext = (-20, 20),
        textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

    def update_position(e):
        x2, y2, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(1,1,1, ax.get_proj())
        label.xy = x2,y2
        label.update_positions(fig.canvas.renderer)
        fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', update_position)
    pylab.show()
```

but the thing is, I manage to update only the last label with this code, I tried to do some loop in the update_position(e) function. But I'm certainly missing something.
So far I used the Axes3D.text(x, y, z, s, zdir) function, but it's not looking really good.

thanks !

Comment: Very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880254/python-plotting-3d-points-with-annotation) recent question.

Comment: not really, if you try the code from this post, when you rotate the plot the annotations stay still

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the identical problem and inspiration for my solution has come from the solutions in:

1. [Matplotlib: Annotating a 3D scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374930/matplotlib-annotating-a-3d-scatter-plot)
2. [Annotate several points with one text in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542232/annotate-several-points-with-one-text-in-matplotlib)

The solution is based on creating an array of "labels", then the position of each "label" gets updated in the update_position() function.

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab  

def update_position(e):
    print "From update position"
    #Transform co-ordinates to get new 2D projection
    tX, tY, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(dataX, dataY, dataZ, ax.get_proj())
    for i in range(len(dataX)):
        label = labels[i]
        label.xy = tX[i],tY[i]
        label.update_positions(fig.canvas.renderer)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return

#Input 3D Data
data = numpy.array([[3,6,2],[4,6,2],[2,9,2],[3,6,10],[6,1,5]])

#Separate into X, Y, Z for greater clarity
dataX = data[:,0]
dataY = data[:,1]
dataZ = data[:,2]

plt.close()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#3D scatter plot
ax.scatter(dataX, dataY, dataZ, marker = 'o', c='b')

#Transform co-ordinates to get initial 2D projection
tX, tY, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(dataX, dataY, dataZ, ax.get_proj())

#Array of labels
labels = []

#Loop through data points to initially annotate scatter plot
#and populate labels array
for i in range(len(dataX)):
    text='['+str(int(dataX[i]))+','+str(int(dataY[i]))+','+str(int(dataZ[i]))+']'
    label = ax.annotate(text,
            xycoords='data',
            xy = (tX[i], tY[i]), xytext = (-20, 20),
            textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'top', fontsize=6,
            bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
            arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))
    labels.append(label)
#Positions are updated when mouse button is released after rotation.
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', update_position)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I've run the code again, and it still runs fine for me.