# How can I have one annotation pointing to several points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data that I usually plot in matplotlib. Certain values of the independent variable are resonances, and I want to label them with something resembling matplotlib's [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate). Is there a way to have one annotation (one balloon that says something like "resonances") with arrows that point to several points on the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about (basically ripped out of the docs http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

coords_to_annote = [(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]

for coords in coords_to_annote:
    ax.annotate('local max', xy=coords, xytext=(3, 1.5),
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
                )


ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Here you are making a lot of text in the same place... I think that using text() and annotate() with an empty field is a better solution. What do you think?

Comment: yeah, I think your's is a bit cleaner

Answer (score 4):

In this form is better to you?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(100)
multi = np.arange(0,100,5)
plt.ylim(-0.5,10)
plt.text(50, 6.5,'a=5k',fontsize=20)
for x in multi:
    plt.annotate("",xy=(x,1),xytext=(50,6),
                 arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.005))
plt.plot(a,'k.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some similar to?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(100)
multi = np.arange(0,100,5)
plt.ylim(-0.5,10)
for x in multi:
    plt.annotate("a=5k",xy=(x,1),xytext=(x,1+4*np.random.rand()),
                 arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
plt.plot(a,'k.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for; I edited my question to clarify. This is still a good answer though, so +1 anyway.